# Transient upvote changes?

Tags: discussion, voting

I've noted that on a recently asked question, I had two upvotes on my question, and then about a half hour later I had zero upvotes.  No entires I could see on the reputation log..

Hard to tell if somebody downvoted the question or whether the original upvoters retracted their upvote.

Anyway to tell what is going on with that?  Why don't I see either the upvotes or the downvotes in the reputation changes?

Comment: Link the question. Then we can try to find out.

Comment: @user202729 because our requests to have a link to the question is not honored. Without it the question is not useful, hence the down votes. This is not a guessing game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need for us to tell you, you should be able to figure it out for yourself in a couple of different ways.

1. Easiest way is to get 1000 rep, and you'll be able to see vote splits.

But since you don't have 1000 rep (yet), there are other options:

2. Look at the reputation tab of your profile (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023110/user1023110?tab=reputation) and
   count the +5 events (or +10 events for answers) and the -2 events for the specific post in question.  Assuming the question was asked recently, you should be able to find all of the events.  Since the reputation tab is sorted by date, the older the post the harder it will be to find everything.
3. Use the timeline view of the question to see the entire history of the post (including the voting history of the question and all answers).  This is not an obvious solution as it is not directly accessible via the UI, but you can manually edit the URL to see it (`stackoverflow.com/posts/{id}/timeline`) where {id} is the post id that appears after `/question/` or in the URL for questions.

For the reputation tab and the timeline view, you'll be able to see high level voting changes.

- If someone upvoted and the quickly removed the upvote within the first 5 minutes, it will not appear at all (basically the vote didn't happen)
- If someone voted and then changed their vote after the first 5 minutes, you'll see separate +10 upvote and -10 unupvote events.
- if someone upvoted and someone else downvoted, you'll see separate +10 and -2 events.

Since you said you said you checked your reputation tab and did not see anything, this means that you had a couple of people upvote your question and then quickly remove the upvotes.  It is also possible you misremember seeing the +2 votes or were looking at the wrong post (which is more likely to happen than you think)

---

If you found timeline view useful and don't want to edit the URL each time, there are some apps to add that functionality, but I don't use any myself, so can't speak to which is best (and there might be more options that didn't show up in my search)

- https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a
- https://stackapps.com/questions/2371/add-timeline-and-revisions-links
- https://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-timeline-and-revisions-links
- https://stackapps.com/questions/4148/view-post-timeline

The timeline view also works for answers but takes more effort to get the post id for an answer, but you can see the voting history of all answers from the question timeline.

Comment: You can see the vote split by using the Stack API and I'm sure there was a script that revealed it for < 1000 rep users but can't find it atm, blame my search skills.